# How to display title with ES6 angular 1.3 controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Just starting to get my head around the ES6 angular controller . I borrowed some code fr here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/es6/2015/01/23/exploring-angular-1.3-using-es6.html.

I am just trying to get a simple controller working and displaying a title.
This is my controller:

```
class PageController {

    constructor(title) {
        this._title = title;
    }

    title () {
        return 'Title: ' + this._title;
    }
}
export { PageController }


import { PageController } from './PageController';

class ProductPageController extends PageController {

    constructor() {
        super('ES6 inheritance with Angular');
    }
}

export { ProductPageController }


import { ProductPageController } from './ProductPageController';

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('ProductPageController', ProductPageController);
```

How can I display the title?
This is a jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/ma6xjbrb/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your methods from a superclass are accessible in derived classes. So you can display title via `title()` method.

You should write the following in the template

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ProductPageController as ctrl">
   {{::ctrl.title()}}
</div>
```

Here is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ma6xjbrb/13/

Comment: Hi just-boris I noticed you removed the traceur reference? So we dont need it?

Comment: Jsfiddle itself can transpile ES6 for you. In your project setup, you maybe use Traceur for it